# keypress is faster than value?

Tags: jquery, keypress

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUc5j/) code :

```
<input id="inputBox" />

$('#inputBox').keypress(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

what I expect to it is, when I insert a value in the input box, have the print of it on the console. Instead, at first value, I get `(an empty string)`, at second value, the first value, and so on...

Why? And how can I fix it? I also read the official [document](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), but nothing about this behaviour!

Comment: Note that `keyup` won't fire until you leave the key(unlike the `keypress` event you used), so if you press one key for two seconds, the callback will be fire just when you leave the key(after two seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is to with the points at which the different keyboard events are fired. To achieve what you want, use `keyup` instead.

```
$('#inputBox').keyup(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ZUc5j/1/)

Comment: Note that `keyup` won't fire until you leave the key(unlike the `keypress` event you used), so if you press one key for two seconds, the callback will be fire just when you leave the key(after two seconds). It can be done with `keypress` see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No...

The `keypress` just get fired **before** the value assigned.
Like every other event(click, submit etc'...) so you can cancel the default behavior and "stuff"

```
$('#inputBox').keypress(function(event) {
    return false; // this will disable the new value assignment
});
```

You can find out what button was clicked with `event.which` and work with it.

Example:

```
<input id="gdoron" />​

$('#gdoron').keypress(function(e){
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    alert(value);
    alert(value + String.fromCharCode(e.which))
})​
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5zsCw/)**

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the timing of events. Here's how it works:

onKeyDown -> onKeyPress -> input value modified -> onKeyUp

If you handle the onKeyUp event, you will be guaranteed in all browsers to have the correct value in the input element.

If you need information about modifier keys and cross-browser implementation, QuirksMode has a [very detailed article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) about it.

Answer (score 0):

there are [3 different key*-events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html). sounds like [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) is what you should use instead.